# rails - ruby - get list items in another list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, list

I have a list of object, contaning

```
obj1
  status
  name
  date
  etc...
obj2
  status
  name
  date
  etc...
etc.
```

And I want to create an another list contaning only names of every objects.

For now, I use this

```
  @object.each do |obj|
    @users << obj.user.name
  end
```

It's working, but I thinks there is a better and faster way to do this.

Anyone ?

Comment: A suggestion, These things you can find easily by googling properly or by reading docs, which gives you self learning capacity.

Comment: I agree with Kranthi.  If you want to be a developer the skill is finding your own answers.   You learn little by asking and getting an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
@user_names = @object.map { |obj| obj.user.name }
```

which returns an array.

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, Can we have separate chat? As here I don't think we can discuss these type of things.